# Правильность вывода формата JSON

Tags: php, html, json

Дорогие друзья, нужна ваша помощь.
Имеется массив `array()` с данными из базы данных.
Когда я пытаюсь их вывести в формат `JSON` они выводятся следующим образом:

```
    { 
    "user":{
      "login":"result",
      "email":"result"
      }
    }
```

На самом деле я не понимаю, как их построить таким образом?
Ниже я привёл пример того как мне нужно вывести данные.
Я не понимаю как этого добиться.
Пробовал и тег `<pre></pre>` и параметр `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, ничего не выходит.

```
    {
  "user" : {"login" : result, "email" : result },
  "user" : {"login" : result, "email" : result },
  "user" : {"login" : result, "email" : result },
  "user" : {"login" : result, "email" : result }
   }
```

Вот пример с сайта https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker
[image: FOTO EXAMPLE]

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php ?

Comment: @splash58 ну написано же в вопрос про pretty уже

Comment: а зачем вам собственно вот именно так выводить его? это формат данных, не важно как он выглядит.  на него не смотреть, а работать с ним надо.

Comment: В принципе Вы правы, не стоит искать ответа на данный вопрос, но всё равно мне как-кто больше нравиться когда всё на своём месте и даже удобней работать, просто понятней что происходит с кодом и можно найти с лёгкостью то что нужно .

Answer (score 0):

Закодируем ваш массив в JSON, передав функции [json_encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) флаг JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, а перед выводом кода HTML-страницы обернём результат в тэг `<pre>`, не забыв экранировать специальные символы, которые могут встречаться в переданных данных.

```
function dump_into_json($data) {
    $json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($json, ENT_NOQUOTES) . '</pre>';
}
```